# Rotation about model's center after moving (pan) the model

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using Three.js to load the JSON model using JSONLoader. I am also using TrackballControls.js for basic interaction. The rotation works differently if I move (PAN) the object. How to change the rotation to the model's center after moving(PAN)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Since the trackball controls rotates the camera not the mesh.The rotation seems to be weird after panning.So instead of using trackballcontrols rotate mesh based on quaternion.
In mousemove event include this code

```
trackBallControls.noRotate = true;
            if (isDragging === true) {
                var deltaMove = {
                    x: event.offsetX -previousMousePosition.x,
                    y: event.offsetY -previousMousePosition.y
                };
                var deltaRotationQuaternion = new THREE.Quaternion()
                        .setFromEuler(new THREE.Euler(toRadians(deltaMove.y * 0.3),
                                toRadians(deltaMove.x * 0.3),
                                0,
                                'XYZ'
                                ));
                if (event.which === 1) {
                    mesh.quaternion.multiplyQuaternions(deltaRotationQuaternion, mesh.quaternion);
                }
            }
            previousMousePosition = {
                x: event.offsetX,
                y: event.offsetY
            };
```

In mouse up event set isDragging to false.
In mousedown set isDragging to true.

```
function toRadians(angle) {
            return angle * (Math.PI / 180);
        }
```

Comment: This is already about rotation around objects center after panning.

Comment: Could you add that in JS fiddle if possible which would be so helpful